# Get image data from trimesh plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to get the pixels of a plot generated with `trimesh`. For other kinds of plots, `getimage` for works for this, but it fails for `trimesh`. Example:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:15,1:15);
tri = delaunay(x,y);
z = peaks(15);
trimesh(tri,x,y,z)

getimage(gca)    % returns [0, 0]
```

My use case requires that I do not actually show that plot, so I can't use `getframe`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `frame2im(getframe(gca))` for your purpose:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:15,1:15);
tri = delaunay(x,y);
z = peaks(15);
trimesh(tri,x,y,z)
img = frame2im(getframe(gca));
```

Comment: Per the question, I can't actually display the plot, so getframe won't work.

Comment: @HansSchwabing strange, what do you get as an output in `img`? Smth like `[0,0]` or `[]`?

Comment: Oops - I spoke too soon! Getframe does work in 2017b (IIRC it didn't in some earlier versions.) Thanks!

Comment: @HansSchwabing glad to hear that :)